# Prevent User Edits to Posts on Certain Days on Any Month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activeadmin

My goal in `ruby` is to not allow a `user` to `edit` on `posts` during certain days of the month throughout the year.

The `first 7 days` of the `month` will be `excluded` as well as the `last 3 days` of any given month.

I see that I can hard code days with each month via the docs, but haven't found if there's a more flexible way than going through each month at a time `excluding` an `array of dates` that aren't hard coded with a particular month.

Using `jQuery UI date-picker` in `active admin` on `rails 5`

If there is an example or someone already asked on how to accomplish this please point me to it.

Thank you for your time.

Edit: I may have found my solution via [GroupDate Gem](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1..7).to_a + (Date.civil(Date.curent.year, Date.curent.month, -3)..Date.civil(Date.curent.year, Date.curent.month, -1)).to_a #disabled days
(8..Date.civil(Date.curent.year, Date.curent.month, -4)) #allowed days
```